# Compatible devices 0?

Tags: android

I got an app in google play and I have a problem.
appears to compatible devices 0.
I tried the application, nexus 6 and nexus 5 y others and works perfectly.
What can i do?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vrt.virtualromaniatvvrt" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: could you please explain a little clearer so we can help ?

Comment: I think you must at least specify a `minSdkVersion` and a `targetSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 3):

When you set uses-feature, is enabled a feature-based Google Play Filtering. Looking to your filtering, you can see that is required the leanback feature. This filtering is used for televisions UI, so I think you must remove it:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much. A to climb again to see if the problem is corrected. You say in a few hours after validation.